# Setup of the region of integration for this triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I am reviewing some Vector Calculus, as a pre-requisite for self-learning PDEs. This is exercise problem 5.4.17, Vector calculus by Colley S.J.

I am having some trouble correctly interpreting the region of integral and setting up the limits of integration. I'd like someone to verify, if my setup is technically correct, and the computation of the bulk integral is fine.

> Integrate the following.
>
> $f(x,y,z)=x+y$; $W$ is the region bounded by the cylinder $x^2 + 3z^2=9$ and the planes $y=0$ and $x + y = 3$.

Both visualization and actual plotting on Geogebra tells us :

[image]

Our region of integration is the part of the red cylinder between the blue plane $x+y=3$ and the purple plane $y=0$.

The axis in red is the $x$-axis, the axis in green is the $y$-axis and the axis in blue is the $z$-axis.

Hence, I set up the limits of the triple integral as :

$$\begin{array}
z = -\sqrt{3 - x^2/3} & \text{ to } & z =\sqrt{3 - x^2/3} \\
y = 0 & \text{ to } & y = 3-x\\
x = -3 & \text{ to } & x = 3
\end{array}$$

Computing the integral

$$\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{3-x} \int_{-\sqrt{3 - x^2/3}}^{\sqrt{3 - x^2/3}} (x + y) \cdot dz \cdot dy \cdot dx$$

yields

$$\frac{81\sqrt{3}\pi}{8}$$

However, the solution manual takes the lower and upper limits of the variable $x$ as $x = 0$ and $x = 3$ respectively. This results in the final integral having value $\frac{81\sqrt{3}\pi}{16}$. I don't exactly follow the rationale for this.

Comment: It seems to me that your answer is correct. Note that the point $(-3,6,0)$ belongs to the given region, but its $x$-coordinate is negative. So, I would say that the answer from the solution manual is wrong.